# Step Slider with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, slider, uislider

How can I make step slider like this in swift?

[image]

there is selected and unselected image for steps on track and custom view (UILabel or UIView) for thumb.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to create your own control or find one on github, there are many. To create your own, you need to work on `UIControl`'s sub-class.

Comment: i google it and just find a library on github with Objective-c : https://github.com/spromicky/StepSlider

Answer (score 0):

take a look this [library](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stepslider) same result as you mentioned in question but if you want to use this in swift then install pod for this library and use that.. or if you want to use this manually after adding such files in a project then you can use bridging header file to convert obj c files function to swift.